# Awesomium WebControl not working with WebSession

Tags: c#, proxy, web-controls, awesomium

I am trying to use WebControl to open websites with a proxy.
I have tryed everything I could find but nothing worked.

I am creating a WebControl, WebPreferences & a WebSession, but when I run the code nothing is displayed.

```
string Proxy = "208.83.6.19:3128";

WebControl wc = new WebControl();
Browsers.Controls.Add(wc);
wc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences() { ProxyConfig = Proxy, SmoothScrolling = true });
wc.WebSession = session;
wc.Source = new Uri("http://checkip.dyndns.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Thanks for all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

It may seem elementary but... when do you add the control to your Form?

```
this.Controls.Add( browser );
```